# Is Siri SDK available?

Tags: ios, sdk, siri

Because of some rumor I'm searching for the Siri API for integrating it to my app.
So, please help me about it.
What this rumor is true or just a rumor.
Is there any trust able API which is serve features like Siri.

Answer (score 2):

The Siri SDK has not yet been made available. It would be a very nice addition, though.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, SiriKit has been released with iOS 10!

However, as a very new feature, only around 7 types of Applications can make use of the API.

I have a YouTube video about how to create a simple Messaging Application using SiriKit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OknS0zecnFU

Answer (score 0):

Rumors continue to say it's coming, now with iWatch adding fuel.

While there is no Siri SDK right now, Nuance does have one (Dragon Mobile).  They are the folks behind Dragon NaturallySpeaking and may even be the folks behind Siri.

Here's [a link to their SDK](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home),
 and a pretty complete [tutorial for putting it in an IOS app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri)

There are several other voice recognition libraries, including free ones like [openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/).